# Arrange kable interactive table by clicking on the column names

Tags: r, kable

I'd like to be able to arrange a table by clicking the column name, like I can with View(.) in R

This is my code

```
library(kable)
library(kableExtra)

titanic %>% 
  kbl() %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"),
                fixed_thead = T) %>% 
  scroll_box(width = "1000px", height = "1000px")
```

I click the column names now and it doesn't re order the columns and that's what I'd like to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this as an answer since I can't comment yet. I'd definetly also recommend using the datatable() package for making interactive tables.

Also just to add, you might find this handy article on combining and using multiple packages to make interactive and beautiful tables.

https://rfortherestofus.com/2019/11/how-to-make-beautiful-tables-in-r/

Comment: I ended up using reactable which has incredible tables

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do that with the kable approach, but as an alternative, it is simple to do with DT package's `datatable()`.

```
#install.packages('DT')
library(DT)

datatable(as.data.frame(Titanic)) # must be either a matrix or data frame
```

It creates an interactive table.
By default, you can click on the column names to rearrange the rows.

Learn more available features and options at https://rstudio.github.io/DT/.